# How to calculate the stopping distance of a wheel collider?

Tags: unity, c#, vehicle

I have an 'AI' bus in my game that needs to pull over occasionally at a bus stop. What I want to do is change the acceleration and brake force based on the stopping distance of the bus. I don't want to simply use the distance between the bus stop and the bus because each time the bus pulls over, it could be traveling at a different speed.

Right now it uses the distance between the bus stop and the bus. It doesn't really work well though because if a bus is traveling faster, it will take a longer distance to stop and will likely go past the bus stop. Same thing if it were going slower.

How do I calculate the stopping distance my bus will take to come to a complete stop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a simple speed-distance-time calculation, and a velocity calculation. This is the code I used:

```
float time = ((distance / currentSpeed) / timeFactor);

float acceleration = (-currentSpeed / time) / vFactor;

v = acceleration;
```

`timeFactor` and `vFactor` are just arbitrary values, which happened to be 1 and 15 respectively.

This may not work for most other people however as this was quite specific to my code.

Answer (score 3):

Let's say that at some point in time you have the current speed `v0` of your bus, which is at some position `x0`, and it needs to stop at position `xs` (s stands for stop).

TL;DR: You have to exert the following force `f` on the bus:

```
f = 0.5 * m * v0^2 / (x0 - xs)
```

where `m` is the mass of the bus.

Details:
The easiest way is to exert a constant force that will drive the bus to a parabolic (in time) curve ending exactly at the bus stop.
The equation for the position `x` at time `t`, and for the velocity `v` are

```
x = x0 + v0 * t + 0.5 * a * t^2
v = v0 + a* t
```

where `a` is the acceleration, which is what we want to calculate.
From the second equation, get `t` as a function of `v`, and plug into the first equation. In this way, you eliminate `t` and find the equation for `x` as function of `v`:

```
x = x0 + 0.5 * (v^2 - v0^2) / a
```

Now *impose* that at `v = 0` you want `x = xs`, and solve for `a`. You get

```
a = 0.5 * v0^2 / (x0 - xs)
```

from which you get the force by multiplying with the mass `m`.

Comment: That looks really good, it's late where I am but I will try this in the morning. Thank you very much!

Comment: It's not really working that well. I tried adding force with a rigid body but it just slowed the bus, it didn't actually stop. Then I tried adding force with ForceMode.Impulse and that stopped the bus almost immediately. I then tried adding that as the brake torque, but again, it stops the bus almost immediately

Comment: If the bus does not stop it means that other forces are acting on it. Try to switch off all other forces while you are exerting the one I discussed in the answer. I am not familiar with the wheel collider of Unity, so I am not sure if that is possible. My answer is somewhat a simplified solution for a simple point particle, that you may adapt to your needs.